# Formatted printing in Java

Tags: java, printing, formatted

I have this code:

```
public String toString(Day day)
{
    String s = day.getDayName() + "    " + day.toString();
    return s;
}
```

This is Day class's toString method:

```
public String toString()
{
    String s = "";
    for (Slot slot: slots)
        s += slot.toString();
    return s;
}
```

When called over and over again it prints:

```
barbi
 monday    10: X 11:   12:   2:   3:   4:
 tuesday    10:   11:   12:   2:   3:   4: X
 wednesday    10:   11:   12:   2:   3:   4:
 thursday    10:   11:   12:   2:   3:   4:
 friday    10:   11:   12:   2:   3:   4:
    bobbi
 monday    10:   11:   12:   2:   3:   4:
 tuesday    10:   11:   12:   2:   3:   4:
 wednesday    10:   11:   12:   2:   3:   4:
 thursday    10:   11:   12:   2: X 3:   4:
 friday    10:   11:   12:   2:   3:   4:
    bunny
 monday    10:   11:   12:   2:   3:   4:
 tuesday    10:   11:   12:   2:   3:   4:
 wednesday    10:   11:   12:   2:   3:   4:
 thursday    10:   11:   12:   2:   3:   4:
 friday    10:   11:   12:   2:   3:   4:
```

However, I would like to print it this way:

```
barbi, income is $95.00
Monday    10:   11:   12: X 2:   3:   4:
Tuesday   10:   11:   12:   2:   3:   4:
Wednesday 10:   11:   12:   2:   3:   4:
Thursday  10:   11:   12:   2:   3:   4:
Friday    10:   11:   12:   2:   3:   4:
bobbi, income is $45.00
Monday    10:   11:   12:   2:   3:   4:
Tuesday   10:   11:   12:   2:   3: X 4:
Wednesday 10:   11:   12:   2:   3:   4:
Thursday  10:   11:   12:   2:   3:   4:
Friday    10:   11:   12:   2:   3:   4:
bunny, income is $0.00
Monday    10:   11:   12:   2:   3:   4:
Tuesday   10:   11:   12:   2:   3:   4:
Wednesday 10:   11:   12:   2:   3:   4:
Thursday  10:   11:   12:   2:   3:   4:
Friday    10:   11:   12:   2:   3:   4:
```

I know this works with formatted printing in Java. But I have no clue how to do that.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `String.format()`, which will accept widths.

I think you could change:

```
String s = day.getDayName() + "    " + day.toString();
```

to:

```
return String.format("%9s %s", day.getDayName(), day.toString());
```

And get what you want.

Answer (score 3):

This is the job for [`java.util.Formatter`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

```
    String[][] kvs = {
            { "Name", "Johnny" },
            { "Age", "19" },
            { "Sex", "Female" },
    };
    for (String[] kv : kvs) {
        System.out.println(
            String.format("%-10s:%10s", kv[0], kv[1])
        );
    }
```

This prints:

```
Name      :    Johnny
Age       :        19
Sex       :    Female
```

#### Syntax

```
%[flags][width]conversion
```

- `-` is the flag for left justification
- `s` is the `String` conversion

---

#### On `String` concatenation

Note that you should never build a `String` using `+=` in a loop. You should use a `StringBuilder` instead.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (Slot slot: slots) {
    sb.append(slot.toString());
}
return sb.toString();
```

#### Related questions

- [Difference between string and StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069416/difference-between-string-and-stringbuilder)
- [Why to use StringBuffer in Java instead of the string concatenation operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65668/why-to-use-stringbuffer-in-java-instead-of-the-string-concatenation-operator)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out java.util.Formatter?  It's available from 1.5 btw.