# The method replaceVariables(String) is undefined for the type

Tags: java

I get this message for as many times as I have used `replaceVariables` in my code. I have added the referenced libraries, but I don't know what else to do. Can someone please help me?

**Update**: This is the code:

```
   int k = 0;
for(Xml reg_is:fetchsite.child("site").child("regexps").children("reg"))    
{
if(reg_is.string("name").contains("unique")){


if(reg_is.child("start").content()=="")
    error += "\tNo prefix reg.exp. given.\n";

  else
prefix = HtmlMethods.removeBreaks(replaceVariables(reg_is.child("start").content()));                       

if(reg_is.child("end").content()=="")
    error += "\tNo suffix reg.exp. given.\n";
 else
suffix = HtmlMethods.removeBreaks(replaceVariables(reg_is.child("end").content()));

}
else{
  poleis[k][0]= HtmlMethods.removeBreaks(reg_is.string("name"));
  poleis[k][1] = HtmlMethods.removeBreaks(replaceVariables(reg_is.child("start").content()));//ιδια δομη για ολες τις πολεις
  poleis[k][2] = HtmlMethods.removeBreaks(replaceVariables(reg_is.child("end").content()));
  k++;
 }
}
```

In this part I use my XML in order to find the data from a HTML page that I want.

Comment: Help us help you. Provide more information.

Comment: Add a code snippet that shows your use of that method.

Comment: Which library is this? There are way too many libraries out there with this method.

Answer (score 1):

So, `replaceVariables` needs to be either a method which is declared in the same class, or it needs to be a static method which is imported using [`import static`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html). Since it seems to be a method of the `HtmlMethods` class, my bet is that adding the following line to the imports should fix the problem:

```
import static com.example.HtmlMethods.*;
```

You only need to substitute `com.example` with the actual package name. Another way is to use `HtmlMethods.replaceVariables(x)` in your code instead.

---

That said, doing a `string == ""` is not the way to determine if the string equals an empty string. You should use either

```
if (string.equals("")) {}
```

or

```
if (string.length() == 0) {}
```

or

```
if (string.isEmpty()) {}
```

instead. Be aware that `string` is supposed to be non-`null` here, else you need to add a `string != null` as well or to use `"".equals(string)`.

Comment: i did it and it doesn't accept this oimport the excact message is"the import HtmlMethods cannot be resolved"and off the record i have created a class HtmlMethods so i don't know why this message is coming up :(

Comment: Is it been placed in a package? You should do that, else you cannot import it in classes sitting in a package.

Comment: i don't know why this think is connected with replaceVariables i have the same code in another project and it isn't wrong :(

Comment: +1; feel free to transplant anything from my answer too. I've given up on this one.

Comment: @kate: apparently an older version of the `HtmlMethods` class missing this method is been placed in the classpath? Do you use an IDE? Ctrl+Click the `HtmlMethods` class and explore it.

Comment: ok thanks alot i will try everything i hope that i will find an answer
thanks for your time and your patience

Answer (score 0):

#### On `==` on reference types

`someString == ""` is almost always wrong. `==` is a reference identity comparison. If you want value comparison, use `equals`. In this particular case, you can use either `someString.length() == 0` or [`someString.isEmpty()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29)

#### Related questions

- [`Java String.equals versus ==`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

#### On `+=` on `String`

Be aware that this performs quite horribly (quadratic) with really long strings. If you're doing this in a any sizable loop, you'd definitely see the effect. It'd be better to use a [`StringBuilder`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

#### Related questions

- [String vs StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73883/string-vs-stringbuilder)
- [Why to use StringBuffer in Java instead of the string concatenation operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65668/why-to-use-stringbuffer-in-java-instead-of-the-string-concatenation-operator)
- [StringBuilder and StringBuffer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355089/stringbuilder-and-stringbuffer-in-java)

Comment: Prefer lists to arrays, blah-blah-blah.