# JTextArea display text and strings

Tags: java, string, swing, jtextarea, settext

I have a JTextArea and would like to be able to add multiple arguments to like so: `messageArea.setText("Hi", name, "how are you today?");` However, I am unable to do so, I do not know how to add multiple arguments to the JTextArea.

Comment: Do you mean concatenation of strings? Like combine those three strings so they can be passed as one string? If so, just use '+'. So it would be "hi" + name + " how are you today?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setText()` method takes a single `String` argument, so you have to [concatenate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation) the strings, you want to display.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("Hi").append(name).append(", how are you?");
messageArea.setText(sb.toString());
```

Other method is to simply use the `+` operator:

```
messageArea.setText("Hi"+name+"...");
```

Or use the [`MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) class:

```
messageArea.setText(MessageFormat.format("Hi {0} how are you?", name));
```

Comment: Why use `StringBuilder` instead of `+`?

Comment: I am not talking about to do it using `+`. Read it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65668/why-to-use-stringbuffer-in-java-instead-of-the-string-concatenation-operator) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645020/when-to-use-stringbuilder-in-java) just for your learning and then update the post with your findings.

Comment: Agreed, StringBuilder is a bit too much, but the rest of the answer is great.

Comment: If you concatenate multiple strings, its always a good practice to use the mutable StringBuilder class instead of wasting resources with + concatenation. In this case it's really not much, but since OP looks like a beginner, it's good to hear about it.

Comment: Generally, in JDK 1.6+, the compiler will change the ```+``` to use ```StringBuilder``` anyways.