# SQLite problem of no such column when trying to insert

Tags: android, sqlite

I use Sqlite and I have the following DB , I am developing an application for women which it should contain a login and sign up . I had problems in the database like "no such column"

DataBase

```
public class DB_MJG extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String name ="dataB.db";
public static final int version =1;

//Les atts de la table FEMME
public static final String table_Femme ="Femme";
public static final String ID_F =  "id";
public static final String NOM_F ="nom";
public static final String PRENOM_F="prenom";
public static final String PSEUDO="pseudo";
public static final String MDP="mdp";
public static final String GRP_F="grpSang";
public static final String AGE_F="age";
public static final String POIDS="poids";

public DB_MJG( Context context) {
    super(context, name, null, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String CREATE_TABLE_FEMME = "CREATE TABLE " + table_Femme + "( 
"+ID_F+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                                +NOM_F+" TEXT, "+PRENOM_F+" TEXT " + ")";


    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_FEMME);
    System.out.println("table femme crée");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+table_Femme);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+table_Enfant);

}

//insérer dans la table FEMME
public void insertFemme(Femme f)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues vals = new ContentValues();


    vals.put(NOM_F,f.getNom());
    vals.put(PRENOM_F,f.getPrenom());
     db.insert(table_Femme,null,vals);
     db.close();
}


public ArrayList getFemme()
{
    ArrayList<Femme> femmes = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
     Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +table_Femme, null);
    while(c.moveToNext()){
        Femme f = new Femme(c.getString(1),c.getString(2));
        femmes.add(f);
    }
    return femmes;
}

}
```

Launcher Activity

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 DB_MJG db = new DB_MJG(this);
 SQLiteDatabase database ;
 String s = "";
 private Button log,sign;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    database = openOrCreateDatabase(db.name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null) ;

    db.insertFemme(new Femme("sara","sara"));
    ArrayList<Femme> femmes = db.getFemme();

    TextView textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView13);
    for(Femme f : femmes){
        String ch = "Nom :" +f.getNom() + " Prenom : " 
+f.getPrenom()+"\n";
        s = s +ch;
    }
    textView.setText(s);
}
```

Error

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) table Femme has no column named nom
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting nom=sara prenom=sara
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Femme has no column named             
 nom (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO     
Femme(nom,prenom) VALUES (?,?)
    at 
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native 
 Method)
```

When I compile,it says no such column. I  have defined the nom column. The database has the nom that I am trying to use for inserting but it doesn't work.

Comment: Either delete the App's data, Uninstall the App or increase the Database version (e.g. change `public static final int version =1;` to `public static final int version =2;`) and then rerun the App. There is a good chance that this will fix the issue (The DatabaseHelper's **onCreate** method only runs once automatically when the database is created, so changes to the database structure via the onCreate method are not applied).

Comment: I tried to change the version from 1 to 2 i get this error

Comment: E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: Femme
       E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting nom=sara prenom=sara
       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Femme (code 1      
       SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Femme(nom,prenom) VALUES (?,?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary issue you have is that the database helper's **onCreate** method is only called when the database is created, which is once in it's lifetime.

As such if any changes are made to the structure (schema) by amending the create table SQL, as used in the **onCreate** method, they will not be reflected unless the database is deleted or that the **onCreate** method is invoked some other way.

Often such changes, as least when developing the app, are applied by first doing one of the following :-

1. Deleting the App's data (this deletes the database, so **onCreate** is automatically called).
2. Uninstalling the App (and as a result deletes the App's data).
3. **IF** the **onUpgrade** method is written to drop the changed table(s) and recreate the tables (often/generally by calling the **onCreate** method)

After doing one of the above, rerunning the App will then result in the structure change being applied.

- **Note** the above will result in the loss of existing data and **IS NOT SUITABLE** for an App that has been deployed.

In your case if using option 3, the **onUpgrade** method needs to include the creation of the table(s) after they have been dropped as it only drops the tables.

You code in the MainActivity is also overly complex in that it utilises opening the database without using the SQLite**OpenHelper** to open the database but rather opens it using the SQLiteDatabase **openOrCreate** method (which doesn't result in the SQLiteOpenHelper's (DB_MJG is a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper) **onCreate** method being called). However, by a quirk/luck, when you do start to use the instance of DB_MJG, namely **db**, as the instance was created before openOrCreate method, it actually goes on to call the **onCreat** method.

However, it would be much simpler, to just use one method to open the database.

As such I'd suggest implementing using just the **DB_MJG** DatabseHelper.

## Fix

The essential fix, is to introduce the changed structure. So one of the 3, above should be taken.

if using 3. then amending the **onUpgrade** method  to call the **onCreate** method and then increasing the version number would be required. That is the onUpgrade method could be :-

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+table_Femme);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+table_Enfant);
    onCreate(db); //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED so that onUpgrade creates the tables after they have been dropped
}
```

## Additional/Recommended

#### Close Cursor

in DB_MJG.java the getFemme method leaves the Cursor open. This can result in a too many open databases or cursors excpetion so it is suggested that the line :-

```
c.close();
```

is added to the **getFemme** method, so it becomes :-

```
public ArrayList getFemme()
{
    ArrayList<Femme> femmes = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +table_Femme, null);
    while(c.moveToNext()){
        femmes.add(new Femme(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(NOM_F)),c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(PRENOM_F))));
    }
    c.close(); //<<<<<<<<<< should always close a cursor when finished with it
    return femmes;
}
```

- Note the above also does away with the need for the intermediate Femme object **f**.

#### Use DB_MJG to open the database

There is no need to openOrCreate the database when using a subclass of SQliteOpenHelper as it will do this. So **MainActivity.java** could be :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DB_MJG db; // Only declare the DB_MJG object.
    private Button log,sign;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = new DB_MJG(this);
        db.insertFemme(new Femme("sara","sara"));
        ArrayList<Femme> femmes = db.getFemme();
        TextView textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView13);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED - Use StringBuilder in a loop
        for(Femme f : femmes){
            sb.append("Nom: ").append(f.getNom()).append(" Prenom: ").append(f.getPrenom());
        }
        textView.setText(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

- Note that the above should be changed at the same time or after the fix has been applied.
- Instead of concatenating Strings in a loop a StringBuilder has been used. See -[Why to use StringBuffer in Java instead of the string concatenation operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65668/why-to-use-stringbuffer-in-java-instead-of-the-string-concatenation-operator)

Comment: -Could you tell me how to delete the app’s data ?-How to increment the data base version ?

Comment: I still have probleme "no such table : Femme "
i think i have also a probleme in "insert method"

Comment: You delete the App's data from Settings/Apps, then select the App but from there it can depend upon the version of Android, you should also see the option to uninstall the App. Another cause could be the in the manifest, if it has `android:allowBackup="true"` then try changing it to `android:allowBackup="false"`. If the backupManager is active/functioning, this could restore the database. I actually ran your code and the changes numerous times, the insertFemme method works.

Comment: Thank you deleting app's data works so i can continue now , I want just to ask you when the onUpgrade method is executed ?

Comment: @Monir onUpgrade is run when the version number (4th parameter of the super call) is greater than the version number that is stored in the database. The database helper as well as calling onUpgrade alters the version number in the database accordingly.